# How can I add an item to a combo box after an ajax query?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox

I can't manage to find the solution to my problem. I have the combobox example given with JqueryUI.

My source is a Json Ajax and all this works well. But I Want to ADD an item to my combobox (I want to append it to Ajax items) manually which say "ADD A NEW ITEM" and when i click on it, my modal form becomes visible.

I put in my code some comments where I need help to explain my problem more.

```
 $('#combobox_scenario').combobox({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "?module=gestionApplication&action=getListeScenarios&option="+encodeURI($(".ui-combobox:first input").val()),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.test,
                        value: item.test,
                        option: this
                    }
                }));
                //I want to add an item Here !
                //response.add({label: 'Ajouter un Scénario',value: 'Ajouter un Scénario',option : this});
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    },
    selected: function(event, ui) {
        var scenario = ui.item2;
        //if (scenario = "This Item added manually") 
            //MyForm.show()
        //else
            $.ajax({
                url: "?module=gestionApplication&action=getScenario&option="+encodeURI(scenario),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function( data ) {
                    data = data[0];
                    $("#scenario").show();
                    $("#scenario").html('<hr><h2>Informations sur le scénario '+data.TEST+'</h2><p>Description : '+data.DESCRIPTION+'</p>'+'<p>Application : '+data.APPLICATION+'</p>');
                }
            });
        //EndIf
    }
});
```

## Edit

Here's my autocomplete combobox code:

```
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
        var input,
            self = this,
            source = this.options,
            select = this.element.hide(),
            selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
            wrapper = this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                .addClass( "ui-combobox" )
                .insertAfter( select );
        input = $( "<input>" )
            .appendTo( wrapper )
            .val( value )
            .addClass( "ui-state-default ui-combobox-input" )
            .autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 0,

                // Need define source in my main js
                source: this.options.source,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option,
                        item2 : ui.item.label
                    });
                },
                change: function( event, ui ) {
                    if ( !ui.item ) {

                        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                            valid = false;
                        select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                            if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                this.selected = valid = true;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if ( !valid ) {
                            // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                            $( this ).val( "" );
                            select.val( "" );
                            input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

        input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };

        $( "<a>" )
            .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
            .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
            .appendTo( wrapper )
            .button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                },
                text: false
            })
            .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
            .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle" )
            .click(function() {
                // close if already visible
                if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                    input.autocomplete( "close" );
                    return;
                }

                // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                $( this ).blur();

                // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                input.focus();
            });
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
    }
});
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Read http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox and see if it helps.

Comment: It's more a general question here. I got this $.map on response() and i don't know how to add an extra item, i tried add() but dosn't work as it's not an array but a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## New Answer

After a bit of thought about you're requirements, I've updated my answer. Please note I worked from the [JQuery UI example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) code as a basis.

I've made three changes to the combobox widget:

**1. Modify your ajax success function to add the "ADD NEW ITEM" item**

```
var responseContainer = $.map( data, function( item ) {
    return {
        label: item.test,
        value: item.test,
        option: this
    };
})
responseContainer.push({label:'ADD NEW ITEM',value:'ADD NEW ITEM',option:this});
response(responseContainer);
```

**2. Output standard html within the ui-menu-item element instead of
    splitting the text up with `<strong>` tags.**

**3. Added an if statement to the autocomplete select event**

```
if(ui.item.value == "ADD NEW ITEM") {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    $( this ).val( "" );
    select.val( "" );
    input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
    return false;
}
```

**Explanation:** So when an item is selected, it's value is checked to see if it says "ADD NEW ITEM". If it does, we show a dialog and reset the combobox to defaults.

[**Full code example using original JQuery UI widget (JSFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/umSrH/7/)

***Be aware***, we are editing the widget so if you're using it for anything else, this might not be the best option. If I had more time I would look for ways of doing it without editing the widget but alas, time is short.

---

## Original Answer

### Append using JQuery Append()

To add a option element, use JQuerys' append() function:

```
$('select#combobox_scenario').append('<option id="Combobox_Item_AddNewItem" value="Combobox_Item_AddNewItem">ADD A NEW ITEM</option>');
```

This will append the given html to the end of the parent element i.e. just before the closing tag: `...</select>`

Here's the documentation on [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

### Or add to the element directly

An alternative would be adding the option to the select list in the html. Like this:

```
<select>
    // ...
    <option id="Combobox_Item_AddNewItem" value="Combobox_Item_AddNewItem">ADD A NEW ITEM</option>
</select>
```

The problem with this being that the values you're getting via ajax will most probably be appended *before* this.

### Then, show a dialog when selected

Then you want to show a dialog when the element is selected? Ok, on the next line (after appending the new option element), add this too:

```
$("#Combobox_Item_AddNewItem").live("click", function() {

    // Call the dialog ...
    $( "#AddNewItemDialog").dialog();
});
```

Comment: I can't do like this cause i use the autocomplete combobox which create a 'combobox like' with an input. I put u the code in my first question.

Comment: @timmalos I've provided further info that should help answer your question.

Comment: Ok, first of all thx u very much for your answer that helps me for a point. But i seems to have trouble to make u understand my problem. What u did is ok, i did same. The difference is that i Dont use the source in the same way as i get the elem with an AJAX request. In the widget, i got this : source: this.options.source
And when i create the widget, i put the source like this :http://jsfiddle.net/umSrH/
My really problem is that i DONT WANT to add 'ADD New ITEM' in my PHP return, so i need to append to the result of the AJAX query the 'ADD new Item' item, and it's what i can't manage to do

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, I've added how you can modify your ajax success function (point 1 of the answer). If this is helpful, please consider up-voting my answer.

Comment: Dude, you're awesome  ! Thx a lot , really !
I did this : 
$('ul.ui-autocomplete:last').append('<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Ajouter un scénario</a></li>');
     $("ul.ui-autocomplete li:last").live("click", function() {
      $('ul.ui-autocomplete:last').hide();
      $( "#dialog-scenario").dialog("open");
     }); 

But your method is clearly the best ;) But I can't up-voting your answer since i dont got 15 reputation. But as soon i am, i 'll do ;)